# Can't get a script to remember its last scraped results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script in python to get the title of different posts from a website and it is grabbing them flawlessly.

However, what I want this script to do now is remember the last scraped results so that when I run it twice it won't fetch the same results. To be clearer - the script will parse the results as usual in it's first execution but it won't grab the same results in it's subsequent execution until no new posts are found.

***Using csv***:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_posts(url):   
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        yield item.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'
    with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for item in get_posts(link):
            writer.writerow([item])
            print(item)
```

***Using database***:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

def connect():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "",
      database="mydatabase"
    )
    return mydb

def create_table(link):
    conn = connect()
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (name VARCHAR(255))")

    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select(".summary"):
        name = items.select_one(".question-hyperlink").get_text(strip=True)
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO webdata (name) VALUES (%s)",(name,))
    conn.commit()

def fetch_data():
    conn = connect()
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
    for item in mycursor.fetchall():
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table(url)
    fetch_data()
```

The above script parses the same results every time I run it.

***How can I let my script remember the last scraped results so that it won't grab the same results again in it's subsequent execution?***

Comment: storing the result in the db or a .txt file ?

Comment: What about remembering the last scrape URL? If the script takes this Url - break.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: you would have to scrape and compare anyway so why not simply overwrite/write afresh? SO results shift pages so you would have to check every link anyway.

Comment: Questions without effort may still receive useful answers when the answer is _simple_. The problem you are asking about is complex, and your question gives the impression (maybe incorrectly) that you didn't make enough of an effort to understand that there is no simple way of doing what you want to achieve. It's not just _slightly tricky_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a list of **unique ids** for each post, which StackOverflow already does with the `<div class="question-summary" id="some unique id">`.  You can extract this value with the following:

```
def get_posts(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".question-summary"):
        yield item['id'], item.findChild('a', {'class':'question-hyperlink'}).text
```

This returns the unique id, and the title of each question.

Now you need to compare this unique id with the ids already added to your csv file, and if the id already exists, you skip that row.  Here is working code for this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping'
    file = open('./output.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    ids = [row[0] for row in reader] #this extracts first column of each row into a list
    file.close()

    with open('./output.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for id, title in get_posts(link):

            if id not in ids: # if id isn't already in your list of ids, write the row

                writer.writerow([id, title])
```

It's worth noting that this is **not** an optimal solution.  You would be much better off using a database like sqlite or mysql, and adding a unique index to the `id` column for each post.  This way, duplicate posts are automatically handled by the database, and you won't have to pull your entire csv file into memory (twice) for every scrape that you make.

### Example using MySQL

table definition:

```
sql = '''
    CREATE TABLE `webdata` (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    question_title CHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY(question_id)
)
'''

mycursor.execute(sql)
```

Bulk inserting scrape data:

```
def get_posts(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    results = []
    for item in soup.select(".question-summary"):
        question_id = item['id']
        question_title = item.findChild('a', {'class':'question-hyperlink'}).text
        results.append((question_id, question_title))

    return results

sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO `webdata` (question_id, question_title) VALUES (%s, %s)'

mycursor.executemany(sql, get_posts(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the results of a scrape run to some persistent storage - for example, a database or some file, as pointed out in a comment. Then on your next run, read that file first so your program knows what happened in the previous run.

All the nitty-gritty details, such as deciding how and where to store the results, and in which format to store the results, and how to use the results after reading them back, are left as an exercise to the reader.

If you know how to map your scrape results to a relational database schema, I suggest using Python's built-in sqlite to store them.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

On second thought, maybe you can just pickle or cloudpickle your in-memory data to a file, and unpickle on the next run.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html
- https://pypi.org/project/cloudpickle/